# detecting a message box or ok button using python

Tags: python, windows, api, automation

I am an avid python programmer and have been delving into the Windows Api for Python and have been stuck on detecting if an "OK" button or message box has appeared within my computer (whether that be from a third party application or windows).

I know that you can use any of these below to control parts of your computer via mouse clicks and such.

```
import win32api, win32com, win32con, ctypes
```

I am wanting to do something like:

```
if ok_button_appearance == "yes":
   #do something
else:
   #do something else
```

Since python is a very, very versatile language, I feel as if there must be some sort of module that can do this for me, I just haven't been able to find it myself.